# HTML displayed in product title

Tags: commerce

I have a Drupal commerce webshop with two main products having multiple variations.

Those variations have labels containing HTML tags.

My problem is when I add to cart HTML tags are displayed in text...
Does someone know how to solve this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have to select text format to full html  check in `admin/commerce/products/types/product/display` or in `admin/commerce/products/types/product/` your field name and check for format option.